# Website Reviewing Application/Interface

Tags: web, comments, review

I am the technology director at a small nonprofit, and we are in the process of making a new website.  We have several proposed mock-ups of different homepage designs, and need to receive input from our board members.  Is there an online application/program/framework that will receive and organize user comments?  I'm looking for something that will allow commenting while viewing the page, rather than just a message board or wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we developed our own solution easily on my [school's new website](http://www.infographie-sup.be), using the [jquery contactable plugin](http://theodin.co.uk/blog/ajax/contactable-jquery-plugin.html), interfaced to [unfuddle](http://www.unfuddle.com) - a cheap and well designed online bug tracking / project management service. Posting via this interface adds a ticket in our debug tracker. Easy for us, and easy for the user as he can comment while looking at the page. Via PHP, i used a browser detection function to pre-fill the form with the user's OS and browser, as well as the url to the very page he is in while commenting.

That's about as cheap and yet professional as i could imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Try [uservoice.com](http://uservoice.com/).  StackOverflow used to use if for feedback.  I, and some others in our organization, have used the free version for feedback on some of our projects.   I've been generally happy with it.